# response.sendRedirect from a servlet redirects to a pdf which should get downloaded

Tags: java, servlets, pdf

Can you please help me 
1)how to open the pdf in a new browser tab or window. (OR)
2) The pdf should get downloaded directly to the local system.

This is the code i am using,

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+"zseriessection9.pdf"+"\"");
response.sendRedirect(contextPath +"/zseriessection9.pdf");
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you are trying to do and also what errors you are experiencing?

Comment: You first need to understand what a redirect is.

Comment: I have a pdf residing on an enternal webserver. I have a servlet in my application in which i have to access that pdf using a URL. I have the URL with me. The task is that, when that URL is accessed, the pdf should get downloaded or it should open in a new window.

Comment: @PseudoNym01 Hope i am clear with the question now

Comment: The simplest thing that could possibly work is to open a new window with the remote address as its location; why not that?

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried that using the '<script>' tag. But, when the new window opens, the actual parent window is showing a white blank page instead of not changing itself. Don't understand why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have below parameters ,

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.pdf");
                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                baos.writeTo(os);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
```

It will show a browser window to `open` or `save` the pdf file. [`response#getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) makes the trick here and redirect doesnt do this , as it creates a new request

Comment: I have a pdf residing on an enternal webserver. I have a servlet in my application in which i have to access that pdf using a **URL**. I have the URL with me. The task is that, when that URL is accessed, the pdf should get downloaded or it should open in a new window.